# Automatically archiving ActiveModel objects in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback, mongoid

I have an interesting problem related to ActiveModel persistence. Our environment requires certain model updates to behave as follows:

1. The instance which receives the update request is archived, meaning, its state remains as that before the update with the exception of an archived field being set to true.
2. A new instance, with the updated attributes of the original instance but with a new `id`, is created.
3. The object the caller of an update operation is holding on to must behave like the new instance, meaning, this behavior must be encapsulated inside the model as part of traditional update processing.

An `around_update` callback would provide a good hook, potentially, but the tricky part is that the `id` of the existing object must change to the `id` of the new instance and I'm not sure whether this could confuse Rails when it comes to persistence, caching, etc.

I'd appreciate comments on the `around_update` approach as well as new ideas for how to solve this problem. We are using Mongoid 2.4 but I am hoping for an answer that applies to ActiveModel in general.

Comment: Do you know the state_machine gem? Maybe you could use this to set different states..within the transitions from one state to the other you can call functions..for example: state = "created".. Change the state to "updated" triggers the update of your archive boolean, clones the object and creates a new one with initial state "created".. Do you know what I mean? I have the experience, that a simple state machine can help very good. You can realize all stuff within your model.

Comment: I am not sure how a state machine would help here. The question is not about deciding when to perform the archive operation. It is about the implementation of the archive operation.